Сравнение строк без учета пробела
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string da;
  cin >> da;
  if (da == "stop") { // даже если задать "stop op" будет true, как можно заставить строки игнорировать пробелы//
    cout << "true";
  }
  else cout << "false"; 


Вы бы хоть на строки-то посмотрели. Вывели, задумались, почему в da не "stop op", а просто "stop". Почитали бы документацию. Вот это нормальный путь. Программирование (ну, не будем углубляться к пресловутой Аде) лет 50 активно развивалось без Интернета. Зато с отладкой :) И, знаете, это было не худшее решение...

Проблем здесь много. Почему cin, а не современный getline? Где string заголовок?

Похоже вы ожидаете, что cin >> ... прочтет целую строку. Но это не так. cin читает в строковую переменную (типа string) "по словам", отбрасывая все пробелы, табуляции, \n и т.п. символы (кстати, они называются whitespace)


cin >> da;


getline(cin, da);


Каков вопрос, таков и ответ! :)
